# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.EntityInstantiators

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

In my spring boot application, I need to configure two databases, MySQL as primary database and elastic search as secondary data base. I am getting below exception after configured elastic search.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.EntityInstantiators
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:591) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:934) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:879) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
... 61 common frames omitted
enter code here
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**ElasticSearch Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repo")
public class ESConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
                ClientConfiguration
                        .builder()
                        .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                        .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
}
```

**Repository Class**

```
public interface EmployeeRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<Employee, String> {}
```

How can I fix the above mentioned issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I update springboot version.
from 2.1.X to 2.6.X
It works.
the issues of github
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1653